# OSX - Eclipse - ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I really hate to ask this question, because it seems like it's been asked numerous times, but none of the responses have helped me.

I am running OSX 10.7.2 (64bit) on my MacBook. I just did a clean install, new harddrive, and upgraded from 10.6.x.

I'm trying to get Eclipse back up and running, but am not having much luck so far. I've had the Android tools installed and working before, so I'm not missing anything obvious I don't think. I've installed all of the platforms / tools using the `sdk/tools/android` utility, and am now trying to install ADT via `Install New Software` in Eclipse. I first tried Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo - 64bit), and that didn't work. I've removed that, and have installed Helios (3.6.x - 32bit), and am still getting the same error.

I've also tried installing ADT from an archive I downloaded from Google, as opposed to the repository URL (which I've also tried).

Eclipse sees the packages (4) either way, and I'm able to accept the TOS for the items, but then I get an install error:

`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.3.v201012070000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.3.v201012100400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.3.v201012020600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.504.v201102160550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.2.3.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.201.v201101270100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.503.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.103.v201101122108`

Does anyone have any advice? I've downgraded both version and architecture, tried installing from repo and package, and have completely removed and re-added the other two relevant repos (Helios & Eclipse Updates).

**EDIT, for exact steps:**

1. Eclipse > Add software.
2. Work with: "Google - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
3. Check "Developer Tools" group.
4. Choose next, and wait for it to calculate dependencies.
5. Choose next, accept all of the terms, click "Finish".
6. "Installing Software" pops up, I see it gets a .jar and a .xml from the Eclipse site.

**...**

1. And, it looks like it just worked. Seriously!? 6 or 7 tries, and now it works?

Perhaps their repo was down or something..

Comment: Could you explain more about what didn't work when trying to install ADT via Install New Software in Eclipse?

Comment: @yorkw: I've edited the question, and as I was step by stepping it, it magically decided to work. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tried to log each step I was doing, and it magically worked. Their repo must have been down or something on previous attempts.